# In my Junit test case driver.findElement(By.cssSelector) not being executed

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, junit4

For the Junit Test case, I am trying to open a browser, navigate to my site and the enter an email in an field. Although all my commands are correct, I cant understand why does it specifically stops and shows error for line 33 i.e. driver.findElement(By.cssSelector)

```
package JUnitTesting;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class BasicActions {
    WebDriver driver;
    String BaseUrl;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Automation\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        BaseUrl = "https://www.flock.co/in/indexd/";
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
    @Test
    public void test() {
        driver.get(BaseUrl);
        System.out.println("opening the base url");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='main-area']//input[@type='email']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("._g-s-input>input")).sendKeys("testing@mailinator.com");
        System.out.println("Entering a valid email id");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='main-area']/div[2]/div[2]//button[@class ='_g-s-button']")).click();
        System.out.println("Redirecting to web.flock.co");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }



}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: For newer Firefox > 47, you need to get geckodriver. You could download the driver in https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases. Put it in the path, our by setting system property `System.setProperty(“webdriver.gecko.driver”,”Path to geckodriver executable”);`

Comment: @adeealamsz I have already specified that in path. Still it shows me this error

Comment: @Grasshopper following error in console:

org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string

Comment: @ShaikhFarzan Is your css selector working in browser console? Though the issue maybe this if you have a similar tools configuration as this - https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/647

Comment: can you paste class name from css which you want to find?

Answer (score 1):

Appropriate syntax to find element by css class is :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input._g-s-input"));
```

I am assuming '_g-s-input' is your css class name, if not so, please replace it with appropriate css class name.